# php-clamav - gets loaded into *each* Apache process

Tags: php, performance, security, optimization, antivirus

php-clamav is a PHP5 extension that allows to incorporate virus scanning features into the PHP5 scripts.

In http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-clamav/reviews/?sort=usefulness&filter=all#reviews-n-ratings it's mentioned:

> "The problem is the clamav virus database gets loaded into *each*
>   Apache process. That means memory usage per process has jumped from
>   ~16MB, to ~170MB!! COMPLETELY unacceptable. However, I think the
>   project can be recommended if it can be made "production" ready."

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You could also minimize the amount of processes with tweaking apache conf or using front end proxy but you cannot load the virus module and not get the library.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious solution is to [NOT load the extension in every php instance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php).

Or just run the scanner via popen/exec/...etc

Without having looked at the project in any detail, it sounds as if it uses the standalone scanner rather than the scanning daemon+light weight client - the standalone scanner does not make much sense in this context.

Comment: i haven't used the dl function. is there any side effects to it? like, will it take time to load the library etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could have clamav running only in one instance of PHP. Then you can send the stuff to scan to the one instance with SysV queue / exec / tcp / http and return the results.  This way you also skip the initializing penalty of loading the clamav library.

Comment: it sounds a little complicated solution in this case.

Comment: It is. One needs to write a few objects to make it a bit more clear, one for the server and one for the clients.